# Selecting data from a dataframe based on a tuple

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
df = DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
               'ids': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'n']})
```

I want to select all the rows which are in the list

```
[ (1,a), (3,f) ]
```

I have tried using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) like so

```
to_search = { 'vals' : [1,3],
          'ids'  : ['a', 'f']
          }

df.isin(to_search)
```

I expect only the first row to match but I get the first and the third row

```
     ids   vals
0   True   True
1   True  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
```

Is there any way to match exactly the values at a particular index instead of matching any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might create a `DataFrame` for what you want to match, and then `merge` it:

```
In [32]: df2 = DataFrame([[1,'a'],[3,'f']], columns=['vals', 'ids'])

In [33]: df.merge(df2)
Out[33]: 
  ids  vals
0   a     1
```